# Moran's eigenvector spatial regression vs autocorrelation term

Tags: regression, autocorrelation, spatial

Comparing two methods for spatial regression:

1. [Moran's Eigenvector-based spatial regression](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1703/1703.04467.pdf)
2. Regression with a term for spatial autocorrelation e.g. where $Y = \beta X + \gamma MY + \epsilon$ for spatial proximity matrix M.

Is there any sense in combining these, or do they solve the same problem by different means?

Comment: I would say there is not much sense in combining them; if not completely confounded, they're likely to be highly collinear.  Can you say why you might want to?

Comment: Intuitively 1 would appear to handle spatial lag in independent variables while 2 handles spatial autocorrelation in the dependent variable - so you might have both? If picking just one, how would you choose?